# Is there a way to stop Intellisense from importing all Mocha (or other test library) globals into non-test files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, intellisense

I have these files in the same directory.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.1"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{}
```

`index.ts`:

```
export const test = () => 'test'
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```
import assert from 'assert'
import {test} from '.'

describe('test function', () => {
  it('should return test', () => assert.strictEqual(test(), 'test'))
})
```

Even without using `import 'mocha'` in `index.spec.ts`, Intellisense (in VSCode) seems to import the Mocha globals and therefore allows `describe` and `it`. `describe` and `it` are also allowed in `index.ts`.

Is there a way to stop this and allow me to specify that Mocha should only be imported in `index.spec.ts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, but it isn't that nice:

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // put compiler options here
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.src.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"], // or wherever your source files are (e.g. src/**/*.ts)
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // List all the types that the src folder needs
    // (should be everything except for mocha/jest/etc.)
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.test.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts"] // or wherever your tests are
  // Since asking this question I now put my tests in tests/**/*.ts
}
```

While VSCode will use `tsconfig.json` for all files, your build script can pick up if you've used for example `describe` or `test` in your source files:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.src.json && tsc -p tsconfig.test.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.1"
  }
}
```